# 301 redirects and htaccess issue

Tags: .htaccess

I'm fairly new to htaccess, so if this is a noob question I apologize.

Recent I launched a newly designed website, and created 301 redirects for all of the old pages.

An example of one of the redirects is:

```
  redirect 301 /about-busch-systems.html http://www.buschsystems.com/About/The-Busch-Company.php
```

The url:

"redirect 301 /about-busch-systems.html http://www.buschsystems.com/About/The-Busch-Company.php"

is in actuality:

"http://www.buschsystems.com/index.php?p=About&subPage=The-Busch-Company"

The redirect is sending me to the right page, with the proper URL, except the old page is being strung on the end as a variable.

Example:

```
redirect 301 /about-busch-systems.html http://www.buschsystems.com/About/The-Busch-Company.php
```

Sends me to "http://www.buschsystems.com/About/The-Busch-Company.php?p=about-busch-systems

Any ideas of why this is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Because that is [what `Redirect` is supposed to do](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect):

> Then any request beginning with URL-Path will return a redirect request to the client at the location of the target URL. Additional path information beyond the matched URL-Path will be appended to the target URL.

Use [`RedirectMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) if you want more control.